# How do I add buttons on ionic app, that once clicked prompt the user to enter integers

Tags: android, ionic-framework

I am developing a calorie counting app. I've basically used the tabs ionic project and set it up for 2 tabs (meals and calorie calculator). I don't know how I add buttons, that once clicked allow the user to enter calories (positive integers). I'm new to ionic and couldn't find answers.

How do I reference this code for html in my ion-list in tab-dash.html, so that user can click button and enter integer? This is my tab-dash.html:

```
<h4>Breakfast</h4>
<ion-item class = "item-avatar item-button-right" href="#">
<img src="img/breakfast.png">
<button class="button button-assertive" onClick="Enter Number">Calories</button>
```

Replies much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Button In Your Html Page

```
<input type="submit" ng-click="click()">
```

Define this method in your controller

```
angular.module('appname', ['ionic'])

.controller('YourCtrl', function($scope, $ionicModal) {


  // Create and show the popup
  $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('popup.html', function(modal) {
    $scope.popupModal = modal;
  }, {
    scope: $scope,
    animation: 'slide-in-up'
  });



  // Open button CLick
  $scope.click= function() {
    //Show your popup
    $scope.popupModal.show();
  };


})
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I will try this.